# Codename One - Scrolling of ComponentGroup + Accordions + Toggle Buttons

Tags: codenameone

I have a Form (with a BoxLayout.y) that has nested ComponentGroup + Accordions + Toggle Buttons. When the user expands the Accordions (inside the ComponentGroup), the list of Toggle Buttons (inside the Accordions) is long and it doesn't fit in the screen.

The problem is that the Form (occupied by ComponentGroup + Accordions + Toggle Buttons) is not scrollable, I suppose because there is an ambiguity of the meaning of the touching (that could be for selecting an item of the list or to do the scrolling). But, I suppose that in the users' mind there isn't true ambiguity: if the user does a simple tap, then he/she are selecting an item; if the user does a tap and then move the finger without stopping tapping, then he/she are trying to do a scrolling. I suppose that this is the expected behavior in the users' mind... otherwise, if the main ComponentGroup occupies all the screen, the scrolling becomes impossible (that is my case).

At the moment, I found a partial unsatisfying solution adding some millimeters of padding to the main ComponentGroup, so there is few space on the borders of the screen to do the scrolling. However it's not intuitive, because users usually expect to be able to scroll in any place of the Form.

My question is how to enable the scrolling in all the Form.

The following code is an example of the structure of code. The actual code is generated by a complex parser written by me that generates the UI automatically from a json input:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());

// Warning: you need to set the theme property "ComponentGroupBool" to true
Button button1 = new Button("Button 1", "ButtonMenuCategories");
CheckBox button11 = CheckBox.createToggle("Button 1.1");
CheckBox button12 = CheckBox.createToggle("Button 1.2");
Button button13 = new Button("Button 1.3", "ButtonMenuCategories");
CheckBox button131 = CheckBox.createToggle("Button 1.3.1");
CheckBox button132 = CheckBox.createToggle("Button 1.3.2");
CheckBox button133 = CheckBox.createToggle("Button 1.3.3");
CheckBox button14 = CheckBox.createToggle("Button 1.4");
Button button2 = new Button("Button 2", "ButtonMenuCategories");
Button button3 = new Button("Button 3", "ButtonMenuCategories");
Button button4 = new Button("Button 4", "ButtonMenuCategories");
Button button5 = new Button("Button 5", "ButtonMenuCategories");

Accordion accordion13 = new Accordion();
accordion13.addContent(button13, FlowLayout.encloseCenter(ComponentGroup.enclose(button131, button132, button133)));
Accordion accordion1 = new Accordion();
accordion1.addContent(button1, FlowLayout.encloseCenter(ComponentGroup.enclose(button11, button12, accordion13, button14)));
Accordion accordion2 = new Accordion();
accordion2.addContent(button2, new Label("Hello"));
Accordion accordion3 = new Accordion();
accordion3.addContent(button3, new Label("Hello"));
Accordion accordion4 = new Accordion();
accordion4.addContent(button4, new Label("Hello"));
Accordion accordion5 = new Accordion();
accordion5.addContent(button5, new Label("Hello"));

Container menu = FlowLayout.encloseCenter(ComponentGroup.enclose(accordion1, accordion2, accordion3, accordion4, accordion5));

hi.add(menu);
hi.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Form` content pane is scrollable by default unless you explicitly disable it using `setScrollableY(false)`. When you set `BorderLayout` this is implicitly done for you as well. Since you used `BoxLayout` the content of the `Form` is scrollable (which it should be for most cases).

However, `Accordion` is also scrollable which means you have two nested scrollable components. It's hard for me to imagine what you are seeing/feeling here but there is one clear bug, you are missing:

```
accordion13.setScrollableY(false);
accordion1.setScrollableY(false);
accordion2.setScrollableY(false);
//... etc ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I confirm that the problem was the two nested scrollable components :)